# Object Oriented: A difficult case in accessing instances

Tags: class, oop, instance

I have three classes: **Class `A`**, **class `B`**, and **class `C`**.

Inside the code of class `A`, an instance of class `B` and an instance of class `C` are created.

```
Class A{

    public A{

        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

    }

}
```

Classes `B` and `C` have `get()` and `set()` methods that allow to receive information about their instances and manipulate the instances of these classes.

Thus, class `A` is able to access `b` and `c`, for example:

```
Class A{

    public A{

        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        int cLife = c.getLifePoints():

    }

}
```

**My problem is this:**

Class `A` may be able to access the instances `b` and `c`, but **I need class `B` to be able to access the instance `c` too.** (By 'access' I mean get information about the instance or manipulate it).

I can't simply write inside class `B`:

`int cLife = A.c.getLifePoints();`

This is because class `A` isn't a static class. It has an instance that was created in another class, class `D`.

But let's say that for some reason I can't access the instance of class `A`, in order to retrieve a reference to `c` from there.

Is there another way to access the instance `c` from inside class `B`? Please tyr to give me the most 'standard' way there is. Any other way will be great too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want `B` to access the `C` instance created in `A`, you need to pass its reference to the `B` instance, for example:

```
    C c = new C();
    B b = new B(c);
```